# Creating drill down report in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I am trying to display a data table with 'n' number of columns as shown below

```
Begin Date | EndDate | Month | Year | Count of Students
2/1/2014 | 1/31/2015 | Jan | 2014 | 10
3/1/2014 | 2/28/2015 | Feb | 2014 | 20
4/1/2014 | 3/31/2015 | Mar | 2014 | 30
5/1/2014 | 4/30/2015 | Apr | 2014 | 40
```

I want to make this data table interactive by enabling the drill down/drill through functionality, where a user can click on each of the values in the "Count of Students" field to see the underlying raw data behind these numbers 10,20,30,and 40.
For Example, if a user clicks on "10" , he/she should be able to see the student raw data behind that count. This is something similar to the Pivot tables concept in excel , where users can see the underlying data behind the Pivot tables. Is there a way I could do the same thing using R Shiny ?

Comment: Two things: how should the drill down exist in the ui; how did you get the data into the table?  You'll have to create both a ui experience in shiny handles the drill down and a way of handling data that connects a click on '10' to a data frame that can be subset by '10' from that column.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, using the `DT` package to capture the selected rows and subset the main set. Here is an example using the `iris` set:

```
library("dplyr")
library("shiny")
library("DT")

# create a summary table
summary_iris <- group_by(iris, Species) %>%
  summarise(Count = n())

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("summary")
  , dataTableOutput("drilldown")
)


server <- function(input, output){

  # display the data that is available to be drilled down
  output$summary <- DT::renderDataTable(summary_iris)

  # subset the records to the row that was clicked
  drilldata <- reactive({
    shiny::validate(
      need(length(input$summary_rows_selected) > 0, "Select rows to drill down!")
    )    

    # subset the summary table and extract the column to subset on
    # if you have more than one column, consider a merge instead
    # NOTE: the selected row indices will be character type so they
    #   must be converted to numeric or integer before subsetting
    selected_species <- summary_iris[as.integer(input$summary_rows_selected), ]$Species
    iris[iris$Species %in% selected_species, ]
  })

  # display the subsetted data
  output$drilldown <- DT::renderDataTable(drilldata())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: How does R know what Input$summary_rows_selected is ? Since anything with inputid summary_rows_selected is not defined in the code but called directly.

Comment: Never mind got it !
If anyone else had the same question, **input$tableId_rows_selected** is a pre defined function in DT.
https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html