# How do you create a drillable Pivot Table in R Shiny like in Excel?

Tags: r, shiny, pivot-table

Looking to create a drillable Pivot Table in R Shiny based on X rows by X columns for example.   The examples I found online would show multiple rows by 1 column but I want to be able drilled down across different columns.

I found examples online that only shows X rows by 1 column that can be drilled down.

Comment: One way: http://www.pivottabler.org.uk/articles/v14-shiny.html

Comment: Thanks for sending this and it looks like it creates pivot tables but I am looking for the additional functionality to be able to click on the individual numbers and provide the record level details behind those numbers just like an Excel pivot does.  In the following link...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43263879/creating-drill-down-report-in-r-shiny  it provides an example where I can click on the row to drill down to record level but what happens if the pivot table has more than 1 columns?